# Is the rate of change of duration a valid quantity?

Tags: time, differentiation

I was wondering that, if the duration of a recurring event varies as time goes on, what would the magnitude of this quantity be measured in? For instance, if the time for an oscillation of a weighted spring decreases (because of energy loss to resistance etc.) by one second every 5 seconds (just picking arbitrary numbers), what would the unit of this rate of change be? If the duration is measured in seconds, the derivative with respect to time would be in terms of $\frac{t}{t}$ or seconds per second which equates to no unit and obviously doesn't make sense and cannot be correct.

So I'm basically asking if I'm missing something that makes the unit not $\frac{t}{t}$ or otherwise does this quantity actually not make sense and how come?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: *which equates to no unit and obviously doesn't make sense and cannot be correct* It *does* make sense and *is* correct. [Example](https://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/p/Period+Derivative)

Comment: Analogously, you could ask about a length that changes over distance. Average tree height by altitude is a real-world example that I bet someone has actually gone out and measured.

Comment: @Arthur Practically anyone who has taken engineering courses would also be familiar with strain, measured in length change over total length.  This is definitely something measured, on a very regular basis.

Comment: Joe is twice as tall as John. What are the units of "twice"?

Comment: Doesn't 'the duration of a recurring event varies as time goes on' broadly mean 'time changes as the universe expands'?

How is 'seconds per second' grammatically different from 'feet per second'?

I don't have the mathematical language but can't you work from that clear equivalence of 'feet' and 'seconds'?

If we must go that far, can you not work with some sliding scale of 'new to old…' or 'rich or poor…' or even 'fast to slow…' seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a valid quantity.

In your example, if $t$ represents the period of an oscillation which changes over time, then you would express the rate at which this changes by dividing again by time. That is $$k=\frac{t}{\tau}$$ which is dimensionless. This number also happens to be present in problems involving damped harmonic motion (usually in the argument of the exponential function and $\tau$ has physical significance). In relativity, it is fine to state that time (in a stationary frame) flows at the rate of one second per second and differently elsewhere, according to another observer.

But it's not always about dividing seconds by seconds, but by taking some quantity $X$ that is already measured in "something" per unit time, and dividing it again by time. These are quantities that have physical units. For example think about acceleration $$a=\frac vt$$ This is a measure of how velocity changes per unit time and hence has the units of *meters per second per second* or meters per second *squared*. Think about force, which is defined as the time rate of change of momentum. Momentum is measured in kilogram meters per second. Force is therefore how that quantity changes with time, i.e., kilogram meters per second per second, or kilogram meters per *second squared*.

Comment: So would it be more correct to express it as the change in frequency rather than the change in time in that case?

Comment: See my edit above.

Answer (score 3):

My watch runs fast.  It advances two seconds per second.  It also advances two minutes per minute and two years per year.

In other words, my watch runs exactly twice as fast as it should, and that factor of two is dimensionless --- it does not depend on the unit I use to measure time.

Comment: Your watch advances 120 seconds per minute. It also advances 0.033 minutes per second. The number *does* depend on the units you use to measure time. So this seems a somewhat poor justification. The result is indeed dimensionless, but there's value in thinking of it as "time<watch> / time<rest frame>"

Comment: I almost see your point but what your watch is doing very clearly does depend on the units used to measure time.

If yours was the only time-piece, the Question would be pointless. Since fairly clearly, yours is not the only time-piece its measurement of time stands to be compared with all the rest.

Whether this, that or the other measure is correct is a different question altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that rate of change of a time duration can be a meaningful quantity.  Being dimensionless (seconds/second) is not a problem, and can even be an asset since the numerical value does not depend on the units chosen.

For example the Earth's rotation rate slows over time, and the change in length of a day can be measured in milliseconds per year, or seconds per second as desired.

Angles are measured in radians or degrees, but are really dimensionless length per length. There is nothing wrong with this.

Comment: The radian is a derived SI unit though isn't it? Is there a similar unit that is defined by seconds/seconds similar to the radian?

Comment: I am not aware of a time/time unit with a name

Comment: @RC_23 The Lorentz factor is a dimensionless quantity used in relativistic physics that expresses a ratio of coordinate time to proper time. Not sure if that qualifies as a "unit", though.

Comment: @RC_23 the most commonly used "units" are ppm or ppb, that is 10^-6 s/s or 10^-9 s/s.

Comment: unless you count the watch-manufacturer unit of "seconds per month", which is about 0.4 ppm.